# Filtering an array by date in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an data structured like that:

```
8: {
      name: 8,
      type: "group",
      home_team: 15,
      away_team: 16,
      home_result: ' ',
      away_result: ' ',
      date: "2018-06-16T21:00:00+02:00",
      stadium: 4,
      channels: [],
      finished: false,
      group: "d"
    },
    23: {
      name: 23,
      type: "group",
      home_team: 13,
      away_team: 15,
      home_result: ' ',
      away_result: ' ',
      date: "2018-06-21T21:00:00+03:00",
      stadium: 6,
      channels: [],
      finished: false,
      group: "d"
    },
```

And want to create a function that returns the matches of the day.

So, how can I do a function called getMatchesOfDay(), that, with the current data, returns only the matches in the specific day?

Comment: This is JSON not array, from this JSON do you want a set of filtered JSON or array of items. Please confirm.

Comment: it's not array, but it's not JSON either. Do you get the object using `JSON.parse` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
let x = {
    8: {
        name: 8,
        type: "group",
        home_team: 15,
        away_team: 16,
        home_result: ' ',
        away_result: ' ',
        date: "2018-06-16T21:00:00+02:00",
        stadium: 4,
        channels: [],
        finished: false,
        group: "d"
    },
    23: {
        name: 23,
        type: "group",
        home_team: 13,
        away_team: 15,
        home_result: ' ',
        away_result: ' ',
        date: "2018-06-21T21:00:00+03:00",
        stadium: 6,
        channels: [],
        finished: false,
        group: "d"
    }
}

const getMatches= function(date){
    Object.keys(x).forEach((obj) => {
    if (x[obj].date == myDate) {
        console.log(x[obj])
    }
})
}

let myDate = "2018-06-21T21:00:00+03:00"; 
getMatches(myDate)
```

Comment: and for a _real_ array, you can use `filter`

Comment: Changed it. Sorry for the confusion